# Want to return two statements without using 'and'

Tags: python

How to make this return two statements and not use `and`?

```
def needtosenets(self,packet_queue,window_size):
    return len(packet_queue) < window_size and== None
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: The `and` makes it connective (both will be evaluated) and returns whether they are both true or not.

Comment: @user1012451, the righthand side will only be evaluated if the lefthand side is `True`

Comment: @gnibbler that's specific to this case, but in general this is  connective. Just saying.

Comment: @user1012451: Not really. `and` short-circuits in Python, so if the left-hand-side isn't truthy, the right hand side won't be evaluated. `or` behaves similarly.

Answer (score 1):

You can return a tuple:

```
return len(packet_queue) < window_size, endpaseqno is None
```

This will return something of the form:

```
(True, False)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def needtosenets(self,packet_queue,window_size,endpaseqno):
    return (len(packet_queue) < window_size , endpaseqno == None )
```

This will return a tuple. For example :

```
 (False , True)
```

You can then access individual values by returned_tuple[0] or returned_tuple[1] where returned_tuple is the tuple returned by the function.